# Python to unpack key value pairs from various layers of a dict, list, dict structure into separate JSON arrays nested within JSON object

Tags: python, json

Scenario:

I need to extract keys and values from a list of python dictionary structures (constructed in previous steps) into respective 'fields' and 'values' JSON arrays nested in JSON object(s).

This is part of a complex JSON string I am producing where I have multiple for loop iterators nested within iterators but this key value pair is the center of of lollipop and the part I am stuck on and I have no idea how to break out the keys and values into respective arrays. Below is the portion I was able to get returned but this is just returning the individual dict structures in a single 'fields' array:

```
"table": "name", 
"inserts": [
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "National Monument"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am ham-fisting around with several approaches to try and break this out and below is just one of many failed attempts:

```
nameList = [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'National Monument'}, {'id': 1, 'name': "Joe's Bar"} ]

result = []
i = 0
for d in nameList:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[i]["inserts"].append({"fields":k})
        result[i]["inserts"].append({"values":v})
    i += 1

pprint(result)
```

## produces error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

This is what I need returned (please disregard any non valid JSON and focus on just the distillation of key value pairs into separate JSON arrays).

```
"table": "name",
"inserts": [
    {
        "fields": [
            "id",
            "name"
        ],
        "values": [
            1,
            "National Monument"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You can try debuggin yourself by printing at several points index values and some key text which refers to... lets say print statement 1, 2 or 3, etc. This way you see the actual loopings your script is making. Also "'Joe's Bar'" is not possible to be a dict value because 's is not possible. This should be "'Joe's Bar" or....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (decision based on your original structure):

```
fields = []
values = []

for str in struct_s["inserts"][0]["fields"]:
   for k,v in str.items():
      fields.append(k)
      values.append(v)

struct_n = {"table": "name"}
struct_n["inserts"] = [{"fields":fields,"values":values}]

print (struct_n)
```

Output

```
{'table': 'name', 'inserts': [{'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'values': [1, 'National Monument']}]}
```

Comment: The JSON was a bit more nested and complex with additional outer objects and arrays that I didn't include in my example but what you provided is similar to what I tried earlier. My fear was losing the referential integrity when I start splitting key value pairs up like that when I start using real database keys instead of the default ones provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure if you looking for something like that

```
nameList = [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'National Monument'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Joe\'s Bar'} ]
inserts = [None] * len(nameList)
i = 0
for d in nameList:
    inserts[i] = {"fields" : [],"values" : []}
    for k, v in d.items():
        inserts[i]["values"].append(v)
        inserts[i]["fields"].append(k)
    i+=1   

result = {"table": "name"}
result["inserts"] = inserts

print(result)
```

OutPut

```
{'table': 'name', 'inserts': [{'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'values':[1, 'National Monument']}, {'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'values': [1, "Joe's Bar"]}]}
```

Comment: This works with the provided dict structure but I have a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries that contain the individual key value pairs so it requires the triple nested for loop I provided as an answer above. This is similar to one path I had explored before hammering out the TNFL.

Answer (score 0):

Consulted with someone in my organization with a bit more experience than me and came up with this:

```
constJSON = []
i = 0     
for k, v in dictNorm.iteritems():
   constJSON.append({"table":k, "inserts":[]})
   if v:
        for d in v:
            flds = list(d.keys())
            constJSON[i]["inserts"].append({
                         "fields": flds,
                         "values": [d[f] for f in flds]
            })
        i += 1
```

Output (partial as this is a large string that iterates over multiple lists of dict structures representing source db tables and columns or tuples).

```
[{'table': 'place_nm', 'inserts': [{'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'values': [1, u'National Monument']}, ...
```